# How to show loading indicator on images in Angular from rest-api

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, svg

I want to show a loading indicator on my images that come in from a rest-api. My code currently shows loading indicators on the images as the request loads in the data, But as I go to different pages on the pagination, the images don't show the loading indicator on the views, because the loading is only based on when the data has loaded? So how can I show loading indicators in view? My code so far is:

**`component.html`**

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12">
   <img [hidden]="!imageLoader" src="../../../../assets/images/rolling.gif"/>
   <img [hidden]="imageLoader" (load)="this.imageLoader = false;" class="align-self-start mr-5 mb-5 artwork" src="{{itunes.artworkUrl100}}" alt="image">
</div>
```

**`component.ts`**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../../../services/api.service';
import { faSearch } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faRedo } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faHeadphones } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faExternalLinkAlt } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faPlus } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { PlaylistService } from '../../../services/playlist.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.scss']
})
export class ContentComponent {

  public data = '';
  public apiData: any;
  public results = [];
  public loading = false;
  public noData: any;
  clicked = false;
  imageLoader = true;

  p: number = 1;
  faSearch = faSearch;
  faRedo = faRedo;
  faHeadphones = faHeadphones;
  faExternalLinkAlt = faExternalLinkAlt;
  faPlus = faPlus;
  searchQuery: string = "";
  clickMessage = '';

  constructor(
    private api: ApiService,
    private list: PlaylistService
  ) { }

  getAll() {
    this.data = '';
    this.loading = true;
    this.api.getAll(this.searchQuery).subscribe((results) => {
      console.log('Data is received - Result - ', results);
      this.data = results.results;
      this.loading = false;
      if (this.data.length == 0) {
        this.noData = true;
      } else if (this.data.length) {
        this.noData = false;
      } else {
        this.noData = false;
      }
    })
  }

  closeAlert() {
    this.noData = false;
  }

  addSongToPlaylist(itunes) {
    this.list.playlist.push(Object.assign({}, itunes));
    this.list.savePlaylist();
    console.log('Playlist - ', this.list.playlist);
  }

  refresh(): void {
    window.location.reload();
  }

  Search() {
    this.api.getAll(this.searchQuery).subscribe((results) => {
      this.loading = true;
      console.log('Data is received - Result - ', results);
      this.data = results.results;
      this.loading = false;
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.list.getPlaylist();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this with css rather than track each image with some variable to hide/show the spinner.

If you change your component.html to

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12">
   <img (load)="$event.target.classList.add('image-loaded')" class="align-self-start mr-5 mb-5 artwork" src="{{itunes.artworkUrl100}}" alt="image">
   <img class="spinner" src="../../../../assets/images/rolling.gif"/>
</div>
```

and use this css

```
.image-loaded + .spinner {
  display:none;
}
```

The idea is once your image loads, the class 'image-loaded' gets added to the image. The css will then hide the spinner once that happens.

Comment: One of the simplest solutions I've seen :). Perhaps in newer Angular versions `$any($event.target)` wrapper is needed. Or for a cleaner solution the `target` must be cast to `HTMLImageElement` using a pipe.